# Restoring browser history in Android

Tags: browser

In an unrooted Android tablet, is there any way to restore web browser history searches that have been cleared?

It is Chrome web browser, and it's not linked to a Google account. Android version 6.0

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are able to perform disk forensics on the storage medium, this is unlikely, since as far as the application/OS is concerned, it has been deleted.